# get id inside onClick funtion in next js that is already accessble from getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am trying to access id1 from  getServerSideProps inside a onclick funtion
for this i tryed to set a usestate inside getServerSideProps and tyed to access it inside onclick funtion but i am not getting to console.log(id) inside on click funtion is there any other method or what am i doing wrong here
use state

```
function Query({ posts, answerPosts }) {
const [id, setid] = useState();
```

```
 function clickQuestion() {

console.log(id)
    
  }
```

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {

  var id1 = ctx.query;
  setid(id1); //tyred to setstate as id1

const queryRequest = fetch("https://askover.wixten.com/questone/" + id1).then(
    async (res) => await res.json()
  );
  const answerRequest = fetch(
    "https://askover.wixten.com/answersapi/" + id1
  ).then(async (res) => await res.json());

  const responses = await Promise.all([queryRequest, answerRequest]);
  const [posts, answerPosts] = await Promise.all(responses);



  return {
    props: {
      posts,
      answerPosts,
    },
  };

}
export default Query;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below is not tested, but hopefully illustrates the concept.

`getServerSideProps` renders before the component loads and can be used to pass props to the component.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  var id1 = ctx.query;
  // return id1 as a property to component
  return {  props: { id1: id1 } };
}
```

In your component you can then consume the props:

```
function Query (props) {
  console.log(props);

  function clickQuestion() {
    console.log(props.id1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickQuestion}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Query;
```

Comment: i have updated the question as what my return is

Comment: To answer your question about what you are doing wrong: You can not use `useState` inside `getServerSideProps`. Instead you need to pass the `id1` from `getServerSideProps` to your component (as illustrated in the code above).

Comment: i have `function Query({ posts, answerPosts }) { i`nsted of  `const YourComponent = (props) => {` so what changes must i make

Comment: no real changes needed. I've updated my example to match your code.
1 thing you still need to do is return `id1` from your `getServerSideProps` like this: `return {  props: { id1, posts, answerPosts, } } ; `

Comment: 1 potential issue is that `ctx.query` might be `null` or `undefined`. Try setting var id1 = 'Test string'` and then returning `id1` to test your logic.

Comment: nop its not empty i am using this id1 to access `"https://askover.wixten.com/answersapi/" + id1` and i am getiing answer

Comment: i think issue is here `function Query({ posts, answerPosts }) {`

Comment: Perhaps the problem is there.. try not deconstructing `Query({ posts, answerPosts })` and just use `Query(props)` without curly brackets to see what your props actually look like.

Answer (score 1):

Hi `getServerSideProps` running on the server, but `setState` only on client-side thats why you can't use `setState` in `getServerSideProps`. But you can return `id` from  `getServerSideProps` and take this `id` from props on your page.

see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-sandbox-9xiizi?file=/pages/about.js)

Comment: i have updated the question can u find a proper answer accoding to it